# table-layout fixed not working

Tags: html, css

with the following code the CSS table was supposed to hide the content that exceeds the table height (200px). Unfortually this doesn´t work and the table is vertically expanded. Anyone knows why ?

```
 <div style='display:table; border:1px solid blue; 
width:200px; table-layout:fixed; height: 200px'>
  <div style='display:table-row'>
    <div style='display:table-cell; overflow:hidden'>
    contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>
    contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>
    contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style='display:inline-block;width:20px;height:200px;
  border:1px solid red; position:absolute;top:8px;left:220px'>
</div>
```

Thanksç

Comment: Use tables for tabular data

Comment: maybe the overflow:hidden needs to be set on the table?

Comment: This doesn´t work either

`<table style='border: 1px solid green; width:200px; 
  height: 200px; table-layout: fixed'>
  <tr>
    <td>
 contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>
 contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>
 contents<br/>contents<br/>contents<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you need to add a `class` or `ID` to the `divs`. Also, if you really want to create a table, do it normally without heaps of divs without classes or ids. Here is a reference on how to make tables at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Do you know [W3Fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com)? I would rather suggest [MDN: <table> - HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/HTML/Element/table).

Comment: @ComFreek Why stackoverflow community hate w3schools, it is good for beginners

Comment: @Hudixt They had been propagating wrong information some years ago. I don't know whether this is still true, the linked table article seems actually fine.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap everything with `<div style="height: 200px;"> ... </div>`