# CSS table-layout: fixed not working?

Tags: html, css

My original concern was: table are flowing out of the div container. I've searched on how to solve it and ended up using table-layout fixed ([How to prevent HTML tables from becoming too wide](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200704/how_to_prevent_html_tables_from_becoming_too_wide/)) and with this concern.

This question maybe tagged duplicate but these questions are different from mine: [Fixed table layout not filling specified table width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378941/table-layout-fixed-not-working),
[table-layout fixed not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340376/fixed-table-layout-not-filling-specified-table-width)

class of the containing div

```
.cardio-form-container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width: 100%;
}

.cardio-form-container table td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

<div class="cardio-form-container"><table>.....
<tr>
    <td>Contact #</td>
    <td>TextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBox</td>
    <td>Locality</td>
    <td>TextBox</td>
    <td>FILE #</td>
    <td>TextBox</td>
    <td colspan="2">TextBox</td>
    <td>TAPE #</td>
    <td>TextBox</td>
    <td colspan="2">TextBox</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Referring MD</td>
    <td>TB</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td>TB</td>
    <td>Sonographer</td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>
```

- I also tried max-width: 100% with and without important!, set width="100%" in the html table.

Table rows doesn't fit the table and some rows are longer than the other. The image should be able to clearly describe my question.

[image]
[image: Updated]

Comment: Please complete your code. At the moment you have 12 <td> in the top <tr> and 11 <td> in the bottom <tr>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is likely caused by the mismatched number of `<td>`s  on each row, you could try changing the last bit `<td colspan="6"></td>` to `7`.

```css
.cardio-form-container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width: 100%;
}
.cardio-form-container table td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardio-form-container">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Contact #</td>
    <td>TextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBoxTextBox</td>
    <td>Locality</td>
    <td>TextBox</td>
    <td>FILE #</td>
    <td>TextBox</td>
    <td colspan="2">TextBox</td>
    <td>TAPE #</td>
    <td>TextBox</td>
    <td colspan="2">TextBox</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Referring MD</td>
    <td>TB</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td>TB</td>
    <td>Sonographer</td>
    <td colspan="7"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your column counts match:
http://jsfiddle.net/5bcL5csu/

Increase your colspan to 7:

```
<td colspan="7">asdf</td>
```